# PHP функция (Время - Время)

Tags: php

Есть функция, которая отнимает одно время от другого?

Например:

```
2012-02-17 3:21 - 2012-02-15 2:01 = 2 дня 1 час 20 минут 13 секунд
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос, на предмет того как вы оперируете датами в данном случае!

Comment: DateTime::diff() и DateInterval::format() 
UPD. была опечатка DataInterval, sorry

Comment: А вы сами понимаете что это значит? НУ хотя бы - DataInterval и format()

Comment: <?php 
    $d1 = new DateTime('2012-02-17 3:21');
    $d2 = new DateTime('2012-02-15 2:01');
    $int = $d1->diff($d2);
    echo $int->format('%d дней %h часов %i минут %s секунд');
    ?>

2 дней 1 часов 20 минут 0 секунд

Comment: вот то что нужно! 
только вот как быть с дней, дня, день.
также с часов, часа, час.
также с минут, минуты, минута.
также с секунд, секунды, секунда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите, может так?

```
function meinformat($int) {
    function form($n) {
        if($n > 20) $n %= 10;
        if($n == 1) return 1;
        elseif($n > 1 && $n < 5) return 2;
        return 0;
    }
    $years=array("лет", "год", "года");
    $months=array("месяцев", "месяц", "месяца");
    $days=array("дней", "день", "дня");
    $hours=array("часов", "час", "часа");
    $minutes=array("минут", "минута", "минуты");
    $secs=array("секунд", "секунда", "секунды");
    $s = array();
    if($int->y) 
        $s[] = $int->y . ' ' . $years[form($int->y)];
    if($int->m) 
        $s[] = $int->m . ' ' . $months[form($int->m)];
    if($int->d) 
        $s[] = $int->d . ' ' . $days[form($int->d)];
    if($int->h) 
        $s[] = $int->h . ' ' . $hours[form($int->h)];
    if($int->i) 
        $s[] = $int->i . ' ' . $minutes[form($int->i)];
    if($int->s) 
        $s[] = $int->s . ' ' . $secs[form($int->s)];
    return implode(" ", $s);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо alexiz! Функция работает как часы! Теперь осталось сказать:
Еще одна функция в библиотеках появилось
@date    15.02.2012
@author  Alexiz
@link    http://hashcode.ru/questions/80243#80263

Answer (score 1):

Вот хорошая функция склонения числительных:

```
function sklon($num,$period){

        $numret = $num;
        $month = array("месяц","месяца","месяцев");
        $day = array("день","дня","дней");
        $hour = array("час","часа","часов");
        $min = array("минуту","минуты","минут");
        if ($period=='month') $titles = $month;
        if ($period=='day') $titles = $day;
        if ($period=='hour') $titles = $hour;
        if ($period=='min') $titles = $min;
        $cases = array (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
        return $numret." ".$titles[ ($num%100>4 && $num%100<20)? 2 : $cases[min($num%10, 5)] ];

    }
```

Использование:

```
$num = 5;
sklon($num,"day"); // вернет "5 дней"
```

Писалась для своих нужд. Т.е. она принимает и возвращает одно числительное. Можно расширить своими словами. Там, например, "граммы", "буквы", "секунды"... и т.д.